# Colocar palavras em uma lista automaticamente

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa similar a um dicionário. Ao fazer uma lista para armazenar as palavras tem alguma forma das palavras, automaticamente, ficarem entre aspas e terem vírgulas?
Por exemplo, se eu pego varias de palavras de um site usando crtl C tem como eu dar crtl V e as palavras virarem uma lista automaticamente, ou terei que colocar ' ' e , de forma manual?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SO-pt, por favor faça um [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como este site funciona e veja também: [que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8388/13561) e [esse outro manual](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se as palavras forem separadas por espaço você pode fazer assim:

```
lista = []
entrada = input()
palavras = entrada.split(' ')
for palavra in palavras:
    lista.append(palavra)
print(lista)
```

Entrada:
`Estou fazendo um programa similar a um dicionário`

Saída:
`['Estou', 'fazendo', 'um', 'programa', 'similar', 'a', 'um', 'dicionário']`